# Any issue continuing iOS5 development with the iOS6 SDK installed?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'd like to download and install the iOS6 SDK, but I'm concerned that I'll step through a door that I can't step back through.  I need to continue production-ready iOS5 development while playing with iOS6.  Is there any issue about having both SDKs installed?  (I do understand about the OS installed on particular devices; I'll have both iOS5 and iOS6 devices.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I downloaded and installed the new beta.  Since Xcode 4.3, Xcode is mostly self contained and 4.5 exists happily alongside 4.3

Answer (score 2):

You cannot send apps that were generated by beta software to the app store, it will get rejected even if you build the app just for iOS 5. I would suggest that you install Lion/Mountain Lion on an external drive to play around with iOS 6.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that you cannot submit Apps build with beta versions of the SDK to the App Store, but installing Lion/Mountain Lion on an external drive is a bit over the top ;-) You can just download the iOS6 SDK and place the binary of Xcode 4.5 somewhere else on your HDD and run it without any downsides :-) I did it myself and also submitted an App built with the latest public available Xcode without any problems.

Comment: I didn't know that, I always thought that installing a new version of XCode changes the system files and is not only limited to the binary. Will definitely give it a try. (I installed iOS 6 on my iPad, cannot build for it anymore :))

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it. I downloaded 4.5 with iOS 6 SDK and now the "Base SDK" is set to iOS 6 and I cannot change to anything less than 6 and half the libraries we use complain about armv7s slice.

Comment: Edit the Architectures setting from "armv7 armv7s" to just "armv7" in your target's "build settings".

Comment: Yeah, figured that out yesterday. Thanks though.

Comment: I have changed both Architectures and Valid Architectures to "armv7" but still I don't see iOS 5.0 as base SDK. Anyone know what could be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I have found the base SDK doesn't matter. My app runs fine on iOS 6 or iOS5 devices.